# I need programming advice regarding how I should set up a web site against Firestore and handle secure access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I read that Firebase user must be signed in to access in a secure way the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and the [Firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).

My questions regarding this are:(after reading for many days)

How does a website securely access Firestore databas if no user is signed in?
Here's a scenario - User open website and website want to load in a secure way from Firestore databas let's say a list of shopping items. But the user has not signed in so the Firebase security rules must be like "open" unsecure so the website can access right?? (and that is crazy right!)

How in the above does one solve this?
Can the website sign in anonymously(under the hood) and is that advisable?
What if the User suddenly decides to sign into Firebase then the website controls two Authenticated users at the same time? "Website" and "User"? Is this even possible or how to handle this?

I hope you understand what I mean please comment!

Comment: Why close this perfectly fine programming related  question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to ensure all data access is authorized without requiring the user to enter their credentials, and then later allow them to enter their credentials.

In cases like this, you'll want to start by signing the user in with [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth). This gives them a UID without requiring them to enter any credentials, and you can use this UID to ensure the any data the user writes is associated with their UID, and that they can only access data that they're authorized to access.

Then later when the user wants to provide their credentials, you can ]link those credentials to the existing anonymous account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) - so that the user retains access to their existing data.